# Why doesn't ToString work with Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) example (Example 2) Data Binding works and the UI is updated based on the value of `ArtistName`.

If xaml binding is written like this:

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding}" />
```

instead of

```
<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ArtistName}" />
```

then ToString is called on `SongViewModel`, and even if I override it like this:

```
 public override String ToString()
 {
     return Song.ArtistName;
 }
```

the value is not updated through DataBinding. Rest of the code is same as in the example given in the link.

Why doesn't value change in this case?

Comment: You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: It has been implemented, this is why `<Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding ArtistName}" />` works

Comment: Right, it's because it's not saying that the property with the name "whateverNameC#HasAssignedToThatBinding" has not been updated, because you haven't called the event on it.

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine WPF Binding doesn't work that way. If you `{Binding}` then the only way for WPF to refresh that binding is to reset the `DataContext`. It has no `PropertyPath` to follow therefore `INotifyPropertyChanged` cannot be called to refresh that Binding.

Comment: You have this Content="{Binding ArtistName}" which means that the label will databind a property named "ArtistName" and not a property named ToString(). Be carefull with DataContext when you use MVVM.

Comment: @HighCore thanks for explaining, please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF Binding doesn't work that way.

If you `{Binding}` then the only way for WPF to refresh that binding is that you reset the `DataContext`. That Binding has no `PropertyPath` to follow therefore `INotifyPropertyChanged` cannot be called to refresh that kind of Binding.

Comment: In other words, given that _DataContext_ is set to a *SongViewModel*, use `{Binding Path=ArtistName}`.