# WPF ListBox not updating value of bound items when the items change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In the application there is a Listbox bound to an ObservableCollection, then the selected item is bound itself to some labels: when a property of the item is changed in the label the actual object (in this case Multimedia) is updated (as I debugged) but then the listbox doesn't update the displayed value.

The Multimedia class implements INotifyPropertyChanged but I'm not sure if I am using it correctly.

Everything else is working without any problem (the add button adds a new element to the list and it is displayed as it should).

I looked around on different forums and also on stackoverflow and tried different variants but still the property, when updated, it is not updated in the ListBox.

This is the XMAL:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="135" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Name="mediaListBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1"  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mediaListBox, Path=SelectedItem}">

        ...

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Artist}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Genre}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Type}" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Name="cmdAddMedia" Grid.Row="1" Click="cmdAddMedia_Click" Height="45" Margin="0,0,0,2" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Add Item</Button>
</Grid>
```

Then here there is the C# code of the main window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MultiMediaList MyData { get; set; }
    public void AddStuff()
    {
        MyData.Add(new Multimedia() { Title = "My Way", Artist = "Calvin Harris", Genre = "Pop", Type = Multimedia.MediaType.CD });
        MyData.Add(new Multimedia() { Title = "Inglorious Bastards", Artist = "Quentin Tarantino", Genre = "Violence", Type = Multimedia.MediaType.DVD });
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyData = new MultiMediaList();
        AddStuff();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;            
    }
...
}
```

And finally the Multimedia class and the  MultiMediaList class:

```
public class Multimedia : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum MediaType { CD, DVD };

    private string _title;
    private string _artist;
    private string _genre;
    private MediaType _type;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _title + " - " + _artist + " [" + _genre + "] - " + getTypeString();
    }

    private string getTypeString()
    {
       if(Type == MediaType.CD) { return "CD"; }
        else { return "DVD"; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

MultimediaList is just an empty class inheriting from ObservableCollection

```
public class MultiMediaList: ObservableCollection<Multimedia>
{

}
```

If you need I can also upload the full code

Hope you can help me and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Somewhat a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16637780/1997232).

Comment: That was it, thanks for the help!

Comment: As a note, instead of checking `if (PropertyChanged != null)` before calling PropertyChanged better write `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));` It is shorter and safer.

Comment: @Clemens hi can you please give me a brief as why it is safer or refer to doc

Comment: It may change value *after* the check for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are expecting that the ListBox automagically calls the Multimedia object's `ToString()` method whenever one if its properties changes. That's not the case.

Instead of relying on ToString, declare a proper ItemTemplate for the ListBox:

```
<ListBox Name="mediaListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <Run Text="-"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Artist}"/>
                <Run Text="["/><Run Text="{Binding Genre}"/><Run Text="]"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Type}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The TextBlock might be written shorter:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Title}"/> - <Run Text="{Binding Artist}"/> [<Run Text="{Binding Genre}"/>] <Run Text="{Binding Type}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: It worked Thanks! Is there a way to force  the call of the ToString method ?

Comment: Not an elegant one. As an alternative, you may add another property for the string representation, e.g. `DisplayText` and always call `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayText))` when any of the other properties change. Instead of an ItemTemplate, you may then simply set `DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"` on the ListBox.